# Protecting API endpoints of a public contact formular

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-api

I'd like to do the following:

My website is designed as Vue SPA, which performs requests to an Laravel-powered API. This API includes a POST-Route that allows to submit the content of a contact formular.

```
/*Contact Routes*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'contact'], function ($router) {

    /*Send*/
    Route::post('/send', 'ContactApiController@send')
        ->name('api.contact.send');
});
```

Now I'd like to protect this route, so only requests that are submitted from the SPA are allowed, otherwise I guess I'd need to handle a lot of spam once somebody figures out that it's enough to create simple post requests to the API endpoint.

There's no user auth planned on that site at the moment, so I think that Laravel airlock does not work in this scenario.

My question: How can I protect my routes from being accessed externally?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229859/how-to-avoid-unauthorized-use-of-an-api

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. As this is tagged with `laravel` I was hoping for a solution using laravel's tools.

Comment: The point is that there's no silver bullet for isolating an API if it's exposed to the public web - Laravel or not. You'll need a suite of tools. That answer shows several of the things you will likely need based on your requirements.

Comment: Since your question is tagged with laravel-7, you could try [Airlock](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/airlock). From the docs: "Airlock exists to offer a simple way to authenticate single page applications (SPAs) that need to communicate with a Laravel powered API."

Comment: It would probably be better to prevent spam in the first place, rather than trying to limit the input to your SPA only. Consider things like a honeypot or a timegate